# Default mySQl Blob Column or upload an image from server directory

Tags: php, mysql

I have this simple problem but I had a hard time of finding a solution.
I want my web application to have a default user image upon his registration. My application uploads directly the images to the database in a blob type column and I don't want to use directory uploading. Are there any ways that I can set a default value for blob? or any code that upload an image that came from a server directory to mysql database? Thanks

Comment: you could write the code to populate the field, every time you add a row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## From the Documentation:

[BLOB and TEXT columns cannot have DEFAULT values.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html)

### Proposed solution:

Why don't you save the file somewhere on your server where it can be served as a static file, and hyperlink that static file instead if your blob column is null?

Comment: any solution that I can upload an image from a server directory?

Comment: uploading a file from local storage to db only to download from db to serve to client is wasting db resources and io. Is there a reason you desire this design pattern?